# Construct a function so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f'(x)\neq 0$, but almost zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Could any help me with the following problem:

Construct a function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ with the following properties:

- $f\in C^1([0,1])$,
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f'(x)\neq 0$, and
- For any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that $f(x) + \varepsilon|x-y| \geq \frac{1}{2} f(y)$, for any $x,y \in (1-\delta_{\varepsilon},1).$

---

So the key thing here is the number 1/2. If we have the number 1 instead then it implies that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f'(x)= 0$.

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: $\inf f \geq \frac 1 2 \sup f$ will do.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Is it possible to have such a function with the extra condition $lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) =0$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I would like to allow [0,$\infty$) for the codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = 2^{x}$

- $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = 2^x \ln(2)$ is continuous
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} f'(x) = 2 \ln(2) \neq 0$
- $f(x) + \epsilon|x-y| \geq \frac{1}{2} f(y) \ \forall x,y \in (1-\delta_\epsilon, 1) \impliedby f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2} f(y) \iff 2^x \geq 2^{y-1}$ which always holds since $x, y \in [0,1]$ and $f$ is increasing. For any positive $\epsilon$, you can choose any $\delta_\epsilon$ of your choice such that $x,y$ lie in the domain.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Is it possible to have such a function with the extra condition $lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) =0$?

Comment: No, since $f(1) = 0 \notin (0,\infty)$. If you're looking to change the co-domain to $[0, \infty)$, then take $f(x) = 2^{-x}$ and verify that it works.

Comment: I meant [0,$\infty$) for the codomain. However your function $f(x)=2^{-x}$ does not satisfy the extra condition.